# Не находит нужный тег

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Составить программу, которая читает прогноз погоды в заданном городе с сайта [meteoprog.ua](http://www.meteoprog.ua) и сохраняет в файле Excel в отдельной строке текущую дату и прогнозы максимальной и минимальной температуры на каждый из следующих 5 дней. Запрос на погоду в заданном городе:

```
http://www.meteoprog.ua/ua/weather/<місто>/
```

Например,

```
http://www.meteoprog.ua/ua/weather/Kyiv/
```

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import datetime as D
import openpyxl

ENC = 'utf-8'


class WeatherViewParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.done = False
        self.in_p = False
        self.span_count = 0
        self.date=[]
        self.in_span1=False
        self.in_span2=False
        self.temp=[]
        self.found_div=False
        self.information=[]

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if not self.done:
            if tag == 'span' and len(attrs)!=0:
                for i in attrs:
                    if ('dayoffMonth' in i):
                        self.in_p = True
                if tag=='span' and len(attrs)!=0 and attrs[0]==['class','tempDay floatL']:
                    self.found_div=True
                if self.found_div and tag=='span' and attrs[0]==['class' ,'from']:
                    self.in_span1=True
                if self.found_div and tag=='span' and attrs[0]==['class' ,'to'] :
                    self.in_span2=True


    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if not self.done:
            if tag == 'span':
                self.in_p = False
            if tag=='span' and (len(self.temp)==5 or len(self.temp)>5) :
                self.in_span1 = False
            if tag=='span' and (len(self.temp)==5 or len(self.temp)>5):
                self.in_span2 = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if not self.done:
            if self.in_p and len(self.date)==8:
                self.date.append(data)
                print(self.date)

            elif self.in_span1 and self.in_span2 and self.span_count!=1:
                self.temp.append(data)
                self.in_span1=False
                self.in_span2=False
                self.span_count+=1

                if len(self.temp)==2:
                    self.create_list()

    def create_list(self):
        self.inform=self.date[0]+' '+self.date[1]
        self.information.append((self.inform,self.temp[0],self.temp[1]))
        self.temp = []
        self.date = []
        self.span_count = 0

        if len(self.information)==5:
            self.done=True

    def get_date(self):
        return self.date

    def get_temp(self):
        return self.temp

    def get_information(self):
        return self.information


class CityWeather:
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.city=city
        self.inform=None
        self.day=D.datetime.now().date().day
        url = 'http://www.meteoprog.ua/'
        path = {'': "ua/weather/{}/".format(city)}
        url = url + urlencode(path, encoding=ENC)[1:]

        try:
            request = urlopen(url)
            data = str(request.read(), encoding=ENC, errors='ignore')
            Site = WeatherViewParser()
            Site.feed(data)
            self.inform=Site.get_information()

        except HTTPError as e:
            print(e)

    def create_WB(self,file_name):
        WB=openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
        RSh = WB.create_sheet(self.city)
        RSh.append([self.city])
        RSh.append(['Day','Min_temp','Max_temp'])

        for word in self.inform:
            RSh.append([word[0],word[1],word[2]])
        WB.save(file_name)

        print('WELL DONE')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    city1 = 'Kyiv'
    city2='Volnogorsk'
    file_name='Ind_26_1.xlsx'
    City1 = CityWeather(city1)
    City2=CityWeather(city2)
    City1.create_WB(file_name)
    City2.create_WB(file_name)
```

Comment: А какой тег нужный?

Comment: В котором находятся значения минимальной и максимальной  температуры на каждый день